# blacklist file/url with nginx rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, rewrite, blacklist

I am using rewrite rues for nginx.congf like this

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /index.php?title=$1&$2 last;
    }
    if ($uri ~* "\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$") {
        expires max;
        break;
    }
}
```

I need to exclude "site.com/api.php" from the rewrite rule. Anybody can point out how to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Just need to add an explicit break

```
location / {
   if ($uri ~ "api.php") {
        break;
    } 
   if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /index.php?title=$1&$2 last;
    }
    if ($uri ~* "\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$") {
        expires max;
        break;
    }
}
```